# Por que no português não existe o digrafo de "th"?

Tags: gramática, fonologia, mudanças-históricas

No latim existia o digrafo de "th". Por que no português não existe o digrafo de "th"?

Talvez por causa de alguma reforma ortográfica ou porque complicaria o ensino ou problemas na fonologia português?

Comment: [“Este fonema está presente só nos dialectos galegos non seseantes, aqueles que pronuncian *pazo* de forma ben distinta de *paso*”.](https://gl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_galega#Consoantes)  + [“Orixe dos sistemas seseantes actuais”](https://gl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seseo#Orixe_dos_sistemas_seseantes_actuais). :)

Comment: Houve três principais época da ortografia. A primeira foi até XV, quando se escrevia como se falava, com dígrafos jogados, sem regras. Então, até 1911, as pessoas tentavam equilibrar escrever uma palavra etimologicamente e escrevê-la como se falava. Nesta época, usava-se dígrafo *th* (som som de /t/), como em *theatro*. Porém, houve a reforma ortográfica em 1911 em Portugal, que regularizou a escrita e eliminou estes dígrafos etimológicos. No Brasil, foi só em 1943. [*vide*](https://www.redebim.dphdm.mar.mil.br/vinculos/000004/000004c7.pdf)

Comment: Da pronúncia, o dígrafo *th* em latim era o som de /t/ ["aspirado"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspira%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Segundo [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_phonology_and_orthography), este som aspirado veio do grego e provavelmente apenas falantes "educados* o falavam. Então, já era natimorto -- provavelmente.

Comment: Gallego is not Portuguese and is irrelevant here. Everyone knows many Spaniards use th, which is why they can pronounce it in English and Latin Americans generally cannot.

Comment: @Lambie I was showing the confusion between the sound—ɪᴘᴀ /θ/—and the un-Iberian digraph ‹th› that has never been needed nor used for /θ/ on the Peninsula. Galego-português went through the same historical evolution of sibilants as Castilian did, as you will have read in the links. The vestiges of that process remain in a (very) few speakers: [“No norte de Portugal, as consoantes /s/ e /z/ são ápico-alveolares (［s̺］ e ［z̺］), sendo que, na parte interior da região, contrastam com ［s］ e ［z］, representadas por C/Ç e Z.”](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa#Sinopse)

Comment: @tchrist I see no reason to complicate this. Sometimes your over zealous answers go right over people's heads. There is no confusion. th, aka /θ/ does not exist in Portuguese.

Comment: Porque algo não existe em português: Como provar um negativo? Imposível.